# ¿Por qué esta validación no me esta funcionando?

Tags: php

```php
public function addCita ($Next,$Trabajadora,$Cliente,$Concat,$Suma,$Observaciones,$Estado)
   {

       $sql= "SELECT COUNT(Id_Cita) AS amount_of_songs from cita WHERE Id_Trabajadora= :Trabajadora and Fecha_Hora= :Concat and Id_Estado != 3 LIMIT 1";
       $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
       $parameters = array(':Trabajadora' => $Trabajadora,':Concat' => $Concat, ':Estado' => $Estado);
       $query->execute($parameters);
       $existe =  $query->fetch()->amount_of_songs;
```

-Necesito que con esta parte me valide si existe un registro de esta trabajadora, a esta hora y con un estado diferente a 3

```php
        if ($existe>=1) {
            return $existe;
        }elseif($existe<1){
```

-Acá hago la validación de si llega algún campo

```php
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `cita`(`Id_Cita`, `Id_Trabajadora`, `Id_Cliente`, `Fecha_Hora`, `Precio_Total`, `Observaciones`, `Id_Estado`) VALUES (:Next, :Trabajadora, :Cliente, :Concat, :Suma, :Observaciones, :Estado)";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $parameters = array(':Next' => $Next, ':Trabajadora' => $Trabajadora, ':Cliente' => $Cliente, ':Concat' => $Concat, ':Suma' => $Suma, ':Observaciones' => $Observaciones, ':Estado' => $Estado);
        //echo '[ PDO DEBUG ]: ' . Helper::debugPDO($sql, $parameters);  exit();
        return $query->execute($parameters);
        }



    }
```

- Pero Al enviar la validación siempre guarda

Comment: PD: Los parámetros se mandan desde el controlador

Comment: Puede ser el uso de `fetch()` dado que este lo que retorna es un `array` asociando de las columnas. ` [ 'amount_of_songs' : 1 ] ` la forma correcta de acceder es `->fetch()['amount_of_songs']`. Prueba a ver que tal.

Comment: @DiegoMesa No creo que sea eso, ya que lo que retorna es un solo valor, el conteo, no un array